# ajax form submision not working at rating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Here the code for review rating. When I submit the form, the data will not be submitted to database. Any help is welcome.

```
<form id="commentform" method="POST" action="#" class="form form-inline form-contact">
    <p class="push-down-20">
        <input type="text" tabindex="3" size="30" value="" id="url" name="txtTitle">
         <label for="email">REVIEW TITLE<span class="red-clr bold">*</span></label>
    </p>
    <p class="push-down-20">
        <input type="text" aria-required="true" tabindex="1" size="30" value="" id="author" name="txtName" required>
        <label for="author">NAME<span class="red-clr bold">*</span></label>
    </p>
    <p class="push-down-20">
        <input type="email" aria-required="true" tabindex="2" size="30" value="" id="email" name="txtEmail" required>
        <label for="email">MAIL<span class="red-clr bold">*</span></label>
    </p>
    <p class="push-down-20">
        <input type="text" tabindex="3" size="30" value="" id="url" name="txtContact">
         <label for="email">CONTACT<span class="red-clr bold">*</span></label>
    </p>
    <p class="push-down-20">
        <textarea class="input-block-level" tabindex="4" rows="7" cols="70" id="comment" name="txtComment" placeholder="Your Review ..." required></textarea>
    </p>
     <p class="push-down-20">
        <!--<div class="tuto-cnt">-->
             <div class="rate-ex2-cnt">
                <div id="1" class="rate-btn-1 rate-btn"></div>
                <div id="2" class="rate-btn-2 rate-btn"></div>
                <div id="3" class="rate-btn-3 rate-btn"></div>
                <div id="4" class="rate-btn-4 rate-btn"></div>
                <div id="5" class="rate-btn-5 rate-btn"></div>
            </div>
<!--</div>-->
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary bold" type="submit" tabindex="5" id="rate-btn" name="rate-btn">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: what is not happening.. the form is not getting submitted or in server there are no data received...

Comment: is there any js/javascript code related to this

Comment: Just an excerpt from a view is not enough. Please provide us how your controller looks like. Where do you submit your form? If this is POST method then try inside your controller `var_dump($_POST); die();` and see the result...

Comment: The Javascript code is missing. Please add this.

Comment: First of all there are error in submit button `<input class="btn btn-primary bold" type="submit" tabindex="5" id="rate-btn" name="rate-btn">Submit</button>` replace with `<input class="btn btn-primary bold" type="submit" tabindex="5" id="rate-btn" name="rate-btn" value="Submit">`

Comment: Just curious, but isn't the code that you shared for page submit ? Also since the `action="#"`, it is being submitted to the same url. Are you expecting the data in the same path ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the form submitted successsfully first.In the other words, if there's something wrong in the submit button or form definition, background codes will know nothing about what you do! The second step, you said 'the data will not be submitted to database', if the backgound codes already received the data successfully but can't save to database only, I suggest you paste more codes about the saving process, then we can know more about where's the error!